# how to prove series convergence

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Can someone help me to prove convergence of the series $$\sum\limits_{k\ge 0}\frac{\left(\frac{2-\nu}2\right)_k}{k!},$$ where $\nu$ is the positive number and $\left(\frac{2-\nu}2\right)_k$ is falling factorial ?

Answer (score 0):

Let $u_{n}$ be the general term of the series.

Then $\frac{u_{n+1}}{u_{n}} = \frac{\frac{2-v}{2}-k}{(k+1)(\frac{2-v}{2}-k+1)} \rightarrow 0$ as $n \rightarrow +\infty$ (and is positive for $k$ large enough).

You can now conclude using the ratio test (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_test).

Comment: I am grateful to you for assistance.

Answer (score 0):

$\frac{(x)_k }{k! } = \binom{x}{k}$ (Identity in Wikipedia page for falling factorials),

So your sum is just $\sum \limits_{k \geq 0} \binom{\frac{2-v}{2} }{k} = 2^{1-\frac{v}{2}}$,

Which is a finite value, hence the sum converges.

Comment: Thanks a lot for help!